# Brownie: PRIVATE_KEY issue: ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of 0 bytes

Tags: brownie

I am trying to run a script in brownie, but I'm running into this error:

```
ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of 0 bytes.
Terminating local RPC client...
```

I'm using a `.env` file with a `PRIVATE_KEY` environment variable.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: What coin and wallet is this? This is a private key, not phrase you enter right?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You haven't provided information that we can use to help.

Comment: if you are using vscode always remember to command+s your files before you run them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with Brownie and private key environment variables, you'll need to make sure a few things are set.

1. In your `.env` file, you have your `PRIVATE_KEY` variable set correctly. If using a `.env` file, it should look something like:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY='0xasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas'
```

If you exported your private key from metamask, you'll want to append a `0x` to the start of your key.

2. You'll want to make sure your `brownie-config.yaml` is set to include a `.env` file, if that's what you're using to set your environment variable.

In your `brownie-config.yaml`:

```
dotenv: .env
```

3. Then finally, you'll want your environment variable set correctly in your `brownie-config.yaml`, something like:

```
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Where you are using the appropriate $ and bracket syntax.

Comment: @Pratick Collins I followed all the steps you have listed in your answer. But, I am still getting the error `ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of 0 bytes.`

Comment: On doing `source .env` , everything worked. Do we have to run source .env everytime the `.env` file is changed? Or is there a way brownie can detect changes in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

your PRIVATE_KEY in .env should be the wallet metamask private key not the encrypted private key showed the step before or the wallet adress. seems =0 that you didn't set up PRIVATE_KEY in .env

Answer (score 0):

In your main script, add

```
print(os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
```

If it prints [None] in the terminal, that mean its not reading your key. Make your its:

`export PRIVATE_KEY='0xasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas'` [In Ubuntu]

`PRIVATE_KEY='0xasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas'` [In windows]

Make sure to put `0x` before the private key & `=` sign instead of `:` sign